# How to round smoothly 100 percentage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, numbers, int

I have an array of number which can be varied in length

```
let arrayNum = [1 ,5, 3, 12] // could also be [1, 5] or [1, 3, 5, 3, 1] 
let sum = arrayNum.reduce(0, +)
```

To calculate percentage of each element and display on a label, I use this method

```
 for value in arrayNum {
     percentageLabel.text = "\(value * 100 / sum) %"
 }
```

However, the percentage doesnt add up to 100%

```
1 has 4%
5 has 23%
3 has 14%
12 has 57%

total % is 99%
```

Does anyone have a better solution in this case? Thanks.

P.S I don't want them to have fraction values like 99.2% or 40.56%. I only want them to be 99% or 40%.

Comment: Just convert your integer to double

Comment: @Nancy p BTW it's a duplicate , anyway you got the idea , so go on as you wan t

Comment: So you are creating a rounding error and then complaining that there is a rounding error. Yes, because you created it.

Comment: "total % is 99%" Actually it's 98%.

Answer (score 2):

You are deliberately introducing a rounding error and then trying to pretend you didn't. That's never going to work.

It *happens* that for the *particular* cases you gave, you can solve the problem by rounding:

```
let arrayNum = [1 ,5, 3, 12] // could also be [1, 5] or [1, 3, 5, 3, 1] 
let sum = arrayNum.reduce(0, +)
for value in arrayNum {
    let d = (Double(value) * 100 / Double(sum)).rounded()
    let s = "\(Int(d))%"
    percentageLabel.text = s
}

5%
24%
14%
57%
[total is 100%]
```

But you cannot expect that approach to work *universally*; numbers just don't work that way. You have to be arithmetically honest.